# Where did St. Catherine of Siena say "Nothing great is ever achieved without much enduring."?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, catherine-of-siena

Where did St. Catherine of Siena say "[Nothing great is ever achieved without much enduring.](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/191516-nothing-great-is-ever-achieved-without-much-enduring)"?

Comment: When you ask where, what exactly are you asking?  Timeframe, a location, an event?  No where is it written when she said it, just that the quote is affiliated with her directly.